# How to know the correct location of File Path in python?

Tags: python

I have a code as shown below, but I dont know the exact location of the given file. How to find the exact location of file? In code, they have used join method.

````
       ```
       Code:
       kmatrixconfigxlsx = os.path.join('.', "Polarion_InterfacesSSD.xlsx")
       signalmatrixconfigxlsx = os.path.join('.', "SignalMatrice.xlsx")
       sstconfigxlsx = os.path.join('.', "SST.xlsx")

       Output:
       '.\\Polarion_InterfacesSSD.xlsx'
       ```
````

Could you let me know, where the exact file location will be?

Comment: `os.path.abspath(path)`?

Comment: It's possible that `./` means the starting directory of the python module? If you don't see any results there, try to look into `C:\Users\<<your_name>>` if you use Windows.

Comment: Even in C:\Users I cannot find any files. Is there any other place where it will be stored?

Comment: Use abspath as Shubham Sharma said

Answer (score 0):

os.getcwd() shows the current directory.